# Can I use the same IP for endpoints in a mesh VPN network?

Tags: routing, vpn, ospf

I have 3 routers, let's call them A, B, C. I need to configure mesh VPNs (i.e. A-B, B-C, A-C) between them. Can I use the same IP as endpoint (local or remote) IP on the same router?

For example we now have 3 VPN connections:

- A 192.168.1.1 - B 192.168.1.2
- B 192.168.1.2 - C 192.168.1.3
- A 192.168.1.1 - C 192.168.1.3

Will this cause problems? What if there are also OSPF on 3 routers? What if there are multiple concurrent VPN connections (different type) between the same routers using the same endpoint IPs?

Comment: What router model and software version?

Comment: @RonMaupin I'm using RouterOS CHR 6.38.5; however I want to know the general case too.

Comment: Some router software can do this, but some cannot. For example, Cisco has DMVPN that creates a dynamic any-to-any VPN. In your case, unfortunately, MikroTik does not offer optional, paid support, so questions about it are off-topic here.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the same IP as source in multiple VPN as the destination is different and there is no issue if you use the same interface as another type VPN source.
This is the general case, there is no logical reason to deny that